# The asset file 'assets/x.jpg' doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen several videos. I have added images but this time it isn't working. What is the problem here idk. As you can see, in the image everything is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `pubspec.yaml` file looks fine, what the actual problem was your assets folder is inside the `android` folder - which is not fair. Please move the asset folder out of the android folder and paste it directly into your root folder.

So your project structure must be:

```
flutter_application_2/
  - android
  - ios
  - ...
  - assets/
    - x.jpg
    - y.jpg
```

Hope you can catch it! Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

the assets folder should be in the root folder not inside the android folder

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30390895)

Comment: @DaFois actually it does answer his question if he did what is told him it will fix the problem 
in `pubspec.yaml`  he declared assets path as `assets/x.jpeg`
but he put the image instead 
`android/assets/x.jpeg`
so if he moves the assets folder to the root of this project this will fix his problem !

Answer (score -2):

Place it like this. As assets might contain fonts and other assets too

assets:

- assets/images/

or

Try flutter clean. And rebuild your project. It'll work.

Comment: Hey, yes, you are correct assets might contain images, fonts, and many other things. But that's not the case here anyway. OP just wants to add some images to the project. Which is not working as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).